# What is the difference between dtype= and .astype() in numpy?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

Context: I would like to use `numpy ndarrays` with `float32` instead of `float64`.

Edit: Additional context -  I'm concerned about how `numpy` is executing these calls because they will be happening repeatedly as part of a backpropagation routine in a neural net. I'd like the net to carry out all addition/subtraction/multiplication/division in `float32` for validation purposes, as I want to compare results with another group's work. It seems like initialization for methods like `randn` will always go from `float64` -> `float32` with `.astype()` casting. Once my `ndarray` is of type `float32` if i use `np.dot` for example will those multiplications happen in `float32`? How can I verify?

The documentation is not clear to me - http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.dot.html

I figured out I can just add `.astype('float32')` to the end of a numpy call, for example, `np.random.randn(y, 1).astype('float32')`.

I also see that `dtype=np.float32` is an option, for example, `np.zeros(5, dtype=np.float32)`. However, trying `np.random.randn((y, 1), dtype=np.float32)` returns the following error:

```
    b = np.random.randn((3,1), dtype=np.float32)
TypeError: randn() got an unexpected keyword argument 'dtype'
```

What is the difference between declaring the type as `float32` using `dtype` and using `.astype()`?

Both `b = np.zeros(5, dtype=np.float32)` and `b = np.zeros(5).astype('float32')` when evaluated with:

```
print(type(b))
print(b[0])
print(type(b[0]))
```

prints:

```
[ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
0.0
<class 'numpy.float32'>
```

Comment: If the function accepts the `dtype` parameter then use it.  If it doesn't accept that parameter you'll have to use the `astype`.  The effect should be the same (in most cases).  The function that accepts `dtype` might be using `astype` (or equivalent) in its return expression.

Comment: Thanks @hpaulj, is `astype()` more widely accepted than `dtype`? Second, do you know if `astype()` forces a temporary `float64` array first, before copying and casting to whatever type the user provides? Is there a way to get `float32` `ndarray's` without creating a temp array first?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Let's see if I can address some of the confusion I'm seeing in the comments.

Make an array:

```
In [609]: x=np.arange(5)
In [610]: x
Out[610]: array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4])
In [611]: x.dtype
Out[611]: dtype('int32')
```

The default for `arange` is to make an int32.

`astype` is an array method; it can used on any array:

```
In [612]: x.astype(np.float32)
Out[612]: array([ 0.,  1.,  2.,  3.,  4.], dtype=float32)
```

`arange` also takes a `dtype` parameter

```
In [614]: np.arange(5, dtype=np.float32)
Out[614]: array([ 0.,  1.,  2.,  3.,  4.], dtype=float32)
```

whether it created the int array first and converted it, or made the float32 directly isn't any concern to me.  This is a basic operation, done in  compiled code.

I can also give it a float `stop` value, in which case it will give me a float array - the default float type.

```
In [615]: np.arange(5.0)
Out[615]: array([ 0.,  1.,  2.,  3.,  4.])
In [616]: _.dtype
Out[616]: dtype('float64')
```

`zeros` is similar; the default dtype is float64, but with a parameter I can change that.  Since its primary task with to allocate memory, and it doesn't have to do any calculation, I'm sure it creates the desired dtype right away, without further conversion.  But again, this is compiled code, and I shouldn't have to worry about what it is doing under the covers.

```
In [618]: np.zeros(5)
Out[618]: array([ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.])
In [619]: _.dtype
Out[619]: dtype('float64')
In [620]: np.zeros(5,dtype=np.float32)
Out[620]: array([ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.], dtype=float32)
```

`randn` involves a lot of calculation, and evidently it is compiled to work with the default float type.  It does not take a dtype.  But since the result is an array, it can be cast with `astype`.

```
In [623]: np.random.randn(3)
Out[623]: array([-0.64520949,  0.21554705,  2.16722514])
In [624]: _.dtype
Out[624]: dtype('float64')
In [625]: __.astype(np.float32)
Out[625]: array([-0.64520949,  0.21554704,  2.16722512], dtype=float32)
```

Let me stress that `astype` is a method of an array.  It takes the values of the array and produces a new array with the desire dtype.  It does not act retroactively (or in-place) on the array itself, or on the function that created that array.

The effect of `astype` is often (always?) the same as a `dtype` parameter, but the sequence of actions is different.

In https://stackoverflow.com/a/39625960/901925 I describe a sparse matrix creator that takes a `dtype` parameter, and implements it with an `astype` method call at the end.

When you do calculations such as `dot` or `*`, it tries to match the output dtype with inputs.  In the case of mixed types it goes with the higher precision alternative.

```
In [642]: np.arange(5,dtype=np.float32)*np.arange(5,dtype=np.float64)
Out[642]: array([  0.,   1.,   4.,   9.,  16.])
In [643]: _.dtype
Out[643]: dtype('float64')
In [644]: np.arange(5,dtype=np.float32)*np.arange(5,dtype=np.float32)
Out[644]: array([  0.,   1.,   4.,   9.,  16.], dtype=float32)
```

There are casting rules.  One way to look those up is with `can_cast` function:

```
In [649]: np.can_cast(np.float64,np.float32)
Out[649]: False
In [650]: np.can_cast(np.float32,np.float64)
Out[650]: True
```

It is possible in some calculations that it will cast the 32 to 64, do the calculation, and then cast back to 32.  The purpose would be to avoid rounding errors.  But I don't know how you find that out from the documentation or tests.

Comment: Thanks - I'm concerned about how `numpy` is executing these calls because they will be happening repeatedly as part of a backpropagation routine in a neural net.

I'd like the net to carry out all addition/subtraction/multiplication/division  in `float32` for validation purposes, as I want to compare results with another group's work. It seems like initialization for methods like `randn` will always go from `float64` -> `float32` with `.astype()` casting. Once my `ndarray` is of type `float32` if i use `np.dot` for example will those multiplications happen in `float32`? How can I verify?

Comment: The documentation is not clear to me - http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.dot.html

Comment: `np.dot` has compiled `numpy` code that calls routines in some external libraries (BLAS, ATLAS etc).  I think most of those have both float and double versions, and it choose the version that is most compatible with the inputs.  But you'd have to dig into the `numpy` source code to be sure.

Comment: I added a note on `np.can_cast`.

Comment: Okay thanks, that's super helpful. Looks like an email on the dev list-serv or examining some source code may be necessary to figure out if it's implicitly casting to 64 for higher-precision math before casting back to 32 to match output and input dtypes.

Comment: @bobo Old question, but if you're concerned about computation time, the correct answer is to just run `timeit` on both and see which is faster.

Answer (score 3):

```
arr1 = np.array([25, 56, 12, 85, 34, 75])    
arr2 = np.array([42, 3, 86, 32, 856, 46])

arr1.astype(np.complex)
print (arr1)
print(type(arr1[0]))
print(arr1.astype(np.complex))
arr2 = np.array(arr2,dtype='complex')
print(arr2)
print(type(arr2[0]))
```

## OUTPUT for above

```
[25 56 12 85 34 75]
<class 'numpy.int64'>
[25.+0.j 56.+0.j 12.+0.j 85.+0.j 34.+0.j 75.+0.j]
[ 42.+0.j   3.+0.j  86.+0.j  32.+0.j 856.+0.j  46.+0.j]
<class 'numpy.complex128'>
```

It can be seen that astype changes the type temporally as we do in normal type casting but where as the generic method changes the type permanently

Comment: This answer is incorrect. `.astype()` does not mutate the original array, it returns a new array.  So, if you use `arr1.astype(np.complex)` and then try to `print(arr1)`, you are printing the original array, not the new array with a new dtype.

Answer (score 0):

`.astype()` copies the data.

```
>>> a = np.ones(3, dtype=float)
>>> a
array([ 1.,  1.,  1.])
>>> b = a.astype(int)
>>> b
array([1, 1, 1])
>>> np.may_share_memory(a, b)
False
```

Note that `astype()` copies the data even if the dtype is actually the same:

```
>>> c = a.astype(float)
>>> np.may_share_memory(a, c)
False
```

Comment: What does this mean for the inline case where an `ndarray` is declared using `.astype()` ? Is something extra being copied here?

Comment: You mean `np.ones(3, dtype=float).astype(int)`? Yes, it first creates a temporary array of floats, then copies it and casts values to ints, and then discards the temporary.

Comment: No, i mean this: `np.ones(3).astype('float32')` - does this first create a temporary array of `float64` entries, then copy a casted `float32` version of the array to a different location in memory and destroy the original? Or does it just create a `float32` array to begin with?

Comment: Yes, it copies. `.astype` is being called on a temporary.

Comment: That's weird...how can i do `np.random.randn(3,1).astype('float32')` without creating a temporary array first? Per the question, trying `np.random.randn((3,1), dtype=np.float32)` does not work.

Comment: You can't.  `random.randn` does not have a dtype argument in any released version of numpy.

Comment: Thanks - to clarify, are you saying that any method of creating an `ndarray` in `float32` using `.astype()` results in the following three steps: (1) create the array in `float64` (2) copy a version of the array casted to `float32` to a new location in memory (3) discard the `float64` array ? My question is if we can just directly create a `float32` array using .astype(). Thanks

Comment: `astype` accepts a `copy=False` parameter.  See the docs.