# Is it possible to cast dtype of scipy CSR matrix to NPY_FLOAT?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, python-c-api

I have a scipy CSR matrix that was constructed from a COO matrix as follows:

```
coord_mat = coo_matrix((data, (row, col)), dtype=np.float64)
```

It is being used as an input to a library with an underlying C implementation, and I believe that the dtype of my matrix is `double(np.float64)`. However, I'm encountering the following error:

```
ValueError: Buffer dtype mismatch, expected 'flt' but got 'double'
```

I went to do some research and found the [scipy C-api](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/c-api.dtype.html#c.NPY_FLOAT), which informed me that the `NPY_FLOAT` data type is converted to a 32-bit float in C, while the current data type I have corresponds to a 64-bit double. Am I on the right track here? If so, how do I cast the type of the array? I'm not entirely sure how I can call on the `NPY_FLOAT` object in order to cast it.

Any help on this matter would be deeply appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about the `C` interface, I'll try to explain the `coo_matrix` part.

Since you are using the tuple input it splits that into 3 variables

```
obj, (row, col) = arg1
```

then it assigns those to attributes

```
self.row = np.array(row, copy=copy, dtype=idx_dtype)
self.col = np.array(col, copy=copy, dtype=idx_dtype)
self.data = np.array(obj, copy=copy)
```

and since you specified a dtype

```
if dtype is not None:
   self.data = self.data.astype(dtype)
```

If `data`, `row` and `col` are already arrays, any you didn't specify the dtype, the sparse matrix can use those inputs as attributes without copying.  Your dtype parameter will produce a copy.

The sparse matrix is not a `numpy` array, but rather an object that has 3 arrays as attribute.  The matrix accepts the `astype` method, which probably does that same `self.data.astype` action.  So I think you case comes down to: can you cast any array to that type.

Comment: Thanks for the input! That's precisely the problem I'm facing, I suspect I need to cast the array to a `NPY_FLOAT` dtype in order to ensure compatibility - alas I'm not sure how to do so and I can't find documentation online so I've no clue as to whether I'm even on the right track or not.